# Java and objects initialising multiple resources - is there a better way?

Tags: java

In Java, we hit many cases of successfully loading one resource but then failing to load the second resource.

We ended up coming to a pattern for it:

```
public class MultipleResourceHolder implements AutoCloseable {
    private final AutoCloseable resource1;
    private final AutoCloseable resource2;

    MultipleResourceHolder() {
        try {
            resource1 = // create it
            resource2 = // create it
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            close();
            throw t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if (resource1 != null) {
            try {
                resource1.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle it
            }
        }
        if (resource2 != null) {
            try {
                resource2.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // handle it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's obviously a lot of boilerplate here though. It gets slightly uglier again if your class also extends some other class which holds its own resources. Also, having the object close itself feels wrong somehow.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I have tried a CloseableList type of approach where you add the objects to the list and it certainly tidies up close() a bit, but the constructor itself doesn't get any better and it adds a field to the class just to do cleanup. :/

Comment: factory design patter might be of some interest. 
http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any particularly nice way.  The try-with-resources pattern takes care of a *huge* amount of boilerplate (which people would usually get wrong in its absence) in cases where it works, but it isn't always useful.

Note also that there is no decent way for a chained constructor call to safely create resources without risk of leakage if the constructor throws, nor can the constructor of an inheritable class create resources in a fashion which will be robust if a derived-class constructor throws.  I would suggest that contrary to the normal advice about calling virtual methods within a base constructor, the only safe way to have a base constructor create resources is to require derived classes to do all their real setup work in a method called from the base constructor, such that the derived-class constructor doesn't do any work and thus can't throw.  That unfortunately means derived classes can't declare their fields as `final`, but I don't know any good workaround for that.

Upon some further consideration, it may be possible to do things reasonably well if the base class defines a `Parameters` class which includes a `success` flag and a (possibly do-nothing) `Close` method; each derived class should derive a parameter-holding class from that of its parents, including whatever additional parameters it needs.  Each class should have a `protected` constructor which accepts its own derived parameters type, and include a public static factory method which will construct a suitable "parameter" object and pass it to the constructor within a try-with-resources block something like:

```
FancyClass create(params)
{
  FancyClass result;
  try (FancyClassParams params = new FancyClassParams(params))
  {
    FancyClassParams.init();
    result = new FancyClass(FancyClassParams);
    result.init(FancyClassParams);
    FancyClassParams.success = true;
  }
}
```

The constructor for `FancyClassParams` should acquire no resources, and be simple enough that it can never fail; if it's necessary to open any files or otherwise acquire resources before calling the main constructor, that should be done in `init`.  The `close` method for `FancyClassParams` should check whether `success` is set and, if not, clean up any resources that it had acquired.

The above approach would require a fair bit of code in each derived class to ensure cleanup always gets performed as it should, but should robustly clean resources even if exceptions occur at any permissible point in the construction process.

Comment: The other unfortunate issue with that approach is that prevents them using any of the constructor parameters to do their initialisation work, because their abstract method gets called before they can assign them to anything. If only Java had given us the ability to assign fields before calling the constructor...

Comment: @Trejkaz: If each class defines a "parameters" class which is derived from that of its parent class, then the non-chained constructor call could encapsulate all its arguments into a parameters object which would get passed to the base class and could in turn be passed back to the virtual initialization method.

Comment: Ah, quite right, that works. Though I suspect it would be even tidier to pass actual factories up to tell the superclass how to initialise the resources as well - kill two birds with one stone... I might play with this idea in a bit.

Comment: @Trejkaz: I don't think passing a factory quite works.  A normal factory would expect to return a new instance, and that can't happen until after the constructor completes.  One could pass an object with a virtual method which would accept a reference to the object under construction and configure it suitably (instead of using a virtual method in the object under construction for that purpose) but I think the configuration logic belongs in the object under construction; the parameter object really shouldn't hold anything but the parameters necessary for construction.

Comment: @Trejkaz: Having to create a temporary object just for passing parameters, and requiring the most derived virtual method to cast to its derivation would be a bit icky, but it's better than using a `ThreadLocal` for the purpose.  The JVM will block access to any class or inherited instance methods, or to inherited fields, prior to the base constructor call, but classes written in JVM languages other than Java would be allowed by the JVM to store their parameters into their own fields prior to the base call.

Comment: @Trejkaz: See the addendum above.